# C++11 memory model: why can't compiler move statements across load() operations during optimization?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, memory-model

As I understand, for the sequentially consistent and acquire-release memory models if some `x.store(some_value)` operation from one thread is synchronized with a `x.load()` operation from the another one, then:

Rule 1. All memory operations that happen before the `x.store(some_value)` operation must appear before the `x.load()` operation.

This point seems clear to me:

```
-Thread 1-        
 y = 1;            
 x.store(2, memory_order_release);         

-Thread 2-
 if (x.load(memory_order_acquire) == 2)
   assert(y == 1)
```

Here if the compiler places `y = 1` operation after `x.store(2)`, `assert` can fail and this is not the behavior that we expect.

Rule 2. All memory operations that happen after the `x.load()` operation must also appear after the `x.store(some_value)` operation.

But now I'm confused: why can't the compiler move the statements across  `load()` operations? How can it violate the expected behavior of the program? I think of a such example:

```
-Thread 1-        
 x.store(2, memory_order_release); // x == 0 initially       

-Thread 2-
 while (x.load(memory_order_acquire) == 1);
 y = 2; // y == 0 initially
```

Here, if compiler places `y = 2` operation before `while()`, `y` becomes `2` (otherwise there is the infinite loop and `y` stays unchanged), but this example seems forced (I'm even not sure that compiler can do such "optimization"), and I suspect that there are more realistic situations for which Rule 2 was created.

Could you please give me the explanation of the Rule 2's necessity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If operations after a load could be moved to before the load, the `assert(y == 1)` in thread 2 could occur before the `y = 1` in thread 1, even though (by rule 1) the assignment happens before the store.  Only the two rules *together* ensure that the two statements are executed in the correct order.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you, but `assert(y == 1)` is in `if`-branch, so how compiler could move it before the load?

Comment: The actual `assert` test can't be done until after the `if` has been evaluated, but the value of `y` may be fetched from memory (into the CPU running thread 2) before that, either because of the order of assembly instructions generated by the compiler, or because of [out-of-order execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution) in the CPU.  Fetching data from memory takes time if it isn't in the CPU cache, so the CPU may want to begin the fetch of `y` early so the value will be available when it comes time to do the `assert` check.